# What is a term for devices requiring human input to function (e.g. a wind-up music box)?

Tags: single-word-requests

So the title is probably not very graceful, but that's exactly why I'm asking this question. I'm trying to find a list of toys, machines, etc. that require the human to interact with them to trigger their mechanism, in old movie cameras, this was done by rotating a handle for example.

But I've no idea how to phrase my search, I'm therefore asking if you know a term that might describe these kinds of things?

Comment: There's a difference between a manual lawnmower and a robotic one, but even the latter needs input from a human or trained dog say. Do you mean 'needing human power'? **Hand-powered** and **manual**  are the usual terms.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Exactly.

Comment: Are you thinking about machines where the human power is stored in some way or are you also thinking of ones where the human force is applied immediately? I find your use of the word "trigger" to describe what the human does to be a little confusing, for me 'trigger' means to release stored power as is the case with a mechanical camera shutter for instance. However hand cranking a very early movie camera actually powered the mechanism in the same way as a swivel rattle. Winding up a clockwork toy stores human energy as potential energy. To use that energy we need to trigger the mechanism.

Comment: *manual*...........................

Answer (score 1):

This class of objects (and toys) are referred to as **automata** or **automatous** (toys, objects, etc). Merriam-Webster defines this as "of, like, or suggestive of an automaton ("a mechanism that is relatively self-operating"). [[1](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/automaton), [2](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/automatous)] Compared with modern robotics this may now seem a bit of a misnomer, but historically this refers to all variety of clockwork-driven items, and a quick Google search turns up plenty of toy and non-toy items of the like. A subtype of automatous toys are called **wind-up toys**, because you turn a crank to load a spring with energy ("wind it up") to operate the mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

**Hand-cranked (or hand crank)**

There are *hand crank* generators and radios and lights. Also *hand-cranked* ice cream makers.
[image: Red Cross hand crank radio]

**Wind-up**

There are wind-up toys, requiring "human input" to operate. (Wikipedia at [Wind-up toy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wind-up_toy))